# He left doing it vs Doing it he left

Tags: grammar, word-usage, sentence-construction, sentence-choice

Let's look at two sentences.

1. He left doing it.
   It means when he left he was doing it and here the work of doing wasn't finished. Here the word 'doing' acts as an adverb.
2. Doing it he left. 
   It means first he did it and then he left.

So placing the word 'doing' in different places differs the meanings of the sentences. 
Am I correct.

Answer (score -1):

the first part of the second sentence is "participle clause". sometimes it make people confused, then it would be better to write as below:

> having done it, he left  (he had done it, he left)

it means that, firstly, he did the work, an then he left